# Multiple Drag/Touch Controls

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, touch, drag, unityscript

I am currently working on a pong style game and I am trying to work out how to move both players at the same time on a multi touch device.

The problem is, I cant move each paddle independently I can only move one player if both users are touching the screen at the same time.

Please see below for the JS code , this script is attached to both paddles (GameObjects) -

```
var object : GameObject;
var speed : float = 1;
var distance : float = 5;

function Start () {

Input.multiTouchEnabled = true;

}

function Update () {

     if(Input.touchCount > 0 )
 {
     var touch = Input.touches[0]; ///// <- This is [1] on player 2 script


     if (touch.position.y > Screen.height/2)
 {


 {
      var x = Input.touches[1].deltaPosition.x *speed* Time.deltaTime;
      var y = Input.touches[1].deltaPosition.y *speed* Time.deltaTime;

      transform.Translate( new Vector3(x, 0 ) );


             if (transform.position.x > 2)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(2, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }

        if (transform.position.x < -8)
        {
            transform.position = new Vector3(-8, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
        }
        }      

 }

 }

 }
```

Comment: var touch = Input.touches[0]; This won't always work. There is no guarentee that the touch in the 0th index is always one player's or the other's

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment , how do you think I could rectify rectify the problem ?

Comment: Might want to use [Open source multi touch library](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/touchscript-multi-touch-library-for-unity-released.172955/) which has pretty good tracking of multi touch

Comment: I use TouchScript - an open source touch library. Works well. A bit of a learning curve though. https://github.com/TouchScript/TouchScript